# ruby throws error for nil

Tags: ruby, object, null, oci8

Given the following class:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'oci8'

class DB
  attr_reader :handle
  def initialize(username, password, db)
    @handle = OCI8.new(username,password,db)
    #We show an error if we don't have a handle after we try to connect to the DB
    raise ArgumentError, "Database connection failed" if @handle.nil
  end
end
def main()
  myHandle=DB.new('myUser','myPass','myDB')
  myHandle.handle().exec('select count(*) from vcas.deviceentitlement where rownum <= 100')
end

main()
```

my script fails with error:

```
`initialize': undefined method `nil' for #<OCI8:USER> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/ndefontenay/Ruby/purge_entitlement/entitlement.rb:20:in `new'
    from /home/ndefontenay/Ruby/purge_entitlement/entitlement.rb:20:in `main'
    from /home/ndefontenay/Ruby/purge_entitlement/entitlement.rb:24
```

I thought `nil` was to check whether an object has been created properly, but it looks like it's trying to run a method called `nil` which doesn't exist. What's going on?

Comment: You have not written which file is `entitlement.rb`. And, since you are not showing the entire code, put the line numbers to the code so that it matches the description in the backtrace.

Comment: And, do you think or do you not think that a method called `nil` exists? It sounds like both, which is contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

`@handle.nil?`

llllllllllllllllllllll

See the dot?  The dot means that what follows is a method call.  The method's name is spelled `nil?`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I totally missed the question mark.
Just started learning ruby, a lot to go.
Plenty of things are confusing me still.

Answer (score 0):

The proper method to check whether an object is `nil` is `nil?`

Methods with a question mark at the end of them return a boolean.